# In app Purchase: "Restore" a transaction that has been purchased but not completed

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I've got an app that register a database for the user if he/she signs up for a auto-renewable subscription.

If user have made the purchase and the app crash or server is offline so user is not able to register the database. User need to be able to register the database later.

So question is how do i "restore" a transaction that haven't called this

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
```

If i restart the app and prints this i will get an empty array.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. If you didn't get a chance to call `-finishTransaction:` before the app closed, then you'll be passed the transaction again next time you add yourself as an observer of the payment queue.

Comment: How do i run the code to provide the content (in my case registration) from the transaction that havn't been completed yet? `-updatedTransactions:` will only be executed if the state changes so when i add my self as observer nothing will happen.

Comment: When you add yourself as an observer it should still come through. Have you tried it?