# URL for cancelling an in App purchase in Apple IOS

Tags: ios

I am using Apple with Java to validate an IN app Purchase this way

```
public static void  validateProductPurhcaseReceipt(String receiptData, String VERIFICATION_URL)
    {
        Map outPut = new HashMap();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(VERIFICATION_URL);
            JSONObject requestData = new JSONObject();
            requestData.put("receipt-data", receiptData);
            requestData.put("password", "f1ebdc2f49664d7188b4d83f90131ecf");
            StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(requestData.toString());
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setEntity(requestEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            System.out.println(responseJSON);
            }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

    }
```

The URL i am using is for verifyReceipt is

```
Development mode = https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
Production mode = https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

Could you please tell me what is the URL for Cancel an in app purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any to cancel an IAP. If it is an auto-renewing subscription, the user has an option to cancel the subscription before next renewal from their iTunes settings. If it is a one-time purchase, the IAP either goes through or fails.

Here's an [Apple support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202023) explaining the different types of IAPs

And if you want to find out how to cancel an IAP if verification fails, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906236/iap-how-to-cancel-a-purchased-transaction-if-the-content-download-fails-or-th) discusses it ([and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197231/how-to-cancel-in-app-purchase-if-my-server-fails-and-cannot-provide-content-io)).

Comment: thank you , my question is , is there any option for setting auto renewal to false programaticaly  ?

Comment: None that I know of